# How to prevent Python from allocating more memory for identical Objects?

Tags: python, object, memory-management

I am constructing a large amount of instances with little variety, that only differ based on one member. Because I am constructing so many of these, I want to minimize memory usage by only constructing as many as needed. How can I get python to recognize that an instance of the identical object already, and just to return a reference to that existing object, rather than create a new object?

```
from random import randint
class Value:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

values = [Value(randint(1, 3)) for _ in range(0, 1000)]

Value(1) is Value(1)
id(Value(1)) == id(Value(1))
# Returns False; should return True
1 is 1
id(1) == id(1)
# Returns True; this is how I want my Value class to operate
```

I am only working with 1, 2, and 3, for Value.value, so I don't want thousands of different instances existing in memory, all having value == 1, value == 2, or value == 3.

Comment: Make the `Value` class private; instead have a factory function that returns `values[i]`.

Comment: Its hard to comment on examples of course, but if this is something that can fit in a python or numpy array and then have functions that work on the array, that may be a more memory efficient approach.

Comment: @jasonharper - I think it would be worth showing that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In a slight twist from jasonharper's comment, you can combine a factory function with a cache that will return an existing value once the object is created. If you have python 3.9+ use `functools.cache`

```
import functools

from random import randint
class Value:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

@functools.cache
def get_value(value):
    return Value(value)

values = [Value(randint(1, 3)) for _ in range(0, 1000)]

print(get_value(1) is get_value(1))
```

3.8 and earlier, you can use `lru_cache` but it has a cache size that you have to guess. Not ideal, but...

```
@functools.lru_cache(3)
def get_value(value):
    return Value(value)
```

And you could always preallocate the values you want.

```
import functools

from random import randint
class Value:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

_value_cache = {value:Value(value) for value in range(1,4)}

def get_value(value):
    return _value_cache[value]

values = [Value(randint(1, 3)) for _ in range(0, 1000)]

print(get_value(1) is get_value(1))
```